# How to copy files from Windows host to Docker container

Tags: windows, docker

Looking for a quick solution to copy local files to a Docker container on Windows. I wasn't able to find this in other Stack Overflow solutions.

You might call this mounting a local drive on Windows within a docker container.

Comment: This might be a better topic for documentation then: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/docker/1318/docker-volumes#t=201607260124515812406

Answer (score 3):

Open the Docker settings from the icon on the taskbar:

[image: Docker popup]

Go to 'Shared Drives' and enable your local drive to be made accessible to your containers:

[image: Docker shared drive settings]

Now you can add folders from your shared drive as a volume in a container. Using the `nginx` example from the Docker [getting started guide](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/):

`docker run -it -v c:/Users:/data nginx /bin/bash`

That will give you shell access, where you can find your local files (c:/Users) in the /data directory of your nginx container.

Answer (score 0):

If windows OS is not win 10 pro, then the docker is installed usnig Docker Toolbox.  In this case one may not find settings dialogue option in the taskbar. See here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42326563/mounting-windows-drives-to-access-from-docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42326563/mounting-windows-drives-to-access-from-docker%20%22here/2) for a way to mount windows folders to access from containers.